# What is special about JDBC that makes it unlikeable for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jdbc

Quoting from [Selenium Architecture](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html)

> A natural implementation would have been to provide a database
>   connection to the underlying data store, using something like JDBC.
>   Eventually, we settled on an API that closely models the underlying
>   Javascript implementation because something that modeled typical
>   database access APIs wasn't sympathetic to a Javascript implementation

I have used both Java+JDBC and JavaScript. And I know that JDBC uses a (connection, query, disconnect) model, but could not understand what is special about JDBC that makes it unlikeable for JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript and JDBC are orthogonal things. Can you please further explain what you are asking? From what you quoted I completely agree that their implementation would have not been nice if it was just like JDBC. For a dozen reasons.

Comment: Right, I tend to agree. But I took the quote from the Selenium Architecture document. Did you click on the link?

Comment: I did and they didn't right out and out say it but they alluded to why its not a good idea to model what server side JDBC would look like in Javascript. WebDriver is supposed to help simulate web interactions. You don't get direct DB access from a browser. Its either a RPC to a server or a localstorage call which there is a specific way to do that in Javascript. Makes sense to follow that previously established method.